# dependent and independent variables in the same factor analysis model

Tags: factor-analysis

Ive conducted a factor analysis model to analyse the relationship between two latent variables, constructed of 13 different variables.
is it possible (and does it make sense) to include both the independent and the dependent variables in the same factor analysis model?

Comment: Generally, yes it can be ok (and by ok I mean the parameters can all be identified). Can't say much more without providing specifics about your particular example.

Comment: well, I've conducted factor analysis with th FAMD function in R {FctoMineR}. my independent variable is "acadimic prestige" which cunstructed of 10 different variables. my dependent variable is "public intervention" which constructed of 2 variables. my goal is to detect the relationships between these two phenomenons. when I replace all the variables in one model, I get three different factors. does it make sense ststisticly?